# How to manage mysql database versioning to keep track of changes?

Tags: mysql, sql, git

Can someone tell me the best way to manage database versioning to keep track of changes? We have huge table, store procedure and function. We want to keep track of changes in database definition. Just like we did in code using git.

Comment: You first want to decide whether you want a [state based or migration based approach](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/devops/database-devops/introduction-to-devops-database-delivery/). Then if applicable search for and install an application that will make this easier. Some tools will allow you to do both, i.e. keep a history of the state using git or similar, and also generate migration scripts automatically based on schema comparisons. Find the application and strategy that works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can use TRIGGERS to nofity changes resulted from INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE statements but there is no TRIGGER to capture and notify DDL changes. However there is technique called CDC (Change Data Capture). It captures all changes in DB including DDL changes and replays it in the target data warehouse. You can find complate instruction [here](https://docs.datacoral.com/ingest_connectors/db/mysql_cdc/#:%7E:text=Datacoral%27s%20MySQL%20Change%20Data%20Capture,another%20system%20or%20processing%20events.)

The second alternative is to parse the DB-Logs and filter those SQLs that changes the table structure, such as 'ALTER TABLE ....'